# counting convex quadrilaterals

Tags: matlab, combinations, combinatorics

In a grid 3x3, we have 1038 convex quadrilaterals, known form [oeis](https://oeis.org/A189413). The answer I calculate is 912.

My approach:

I calculate number of convex quadrilaterals in grid smaller than or equal to 3x3, which all points of it is on the boundary of the smaller grid. Then multiply a coefficient. This coefficient is the number of ways that the smaller grid can be placed within the larger one. For example, grid 1x1 can be placed 9 times, and grid 2x1 can be placed 6 times.

My code:

```
n=3;
exclusive1=zeros(n,n);

for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        exclusive1(i,j)=exclusive2(i,j);
    end
end
total=0;
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        total=total+ exclusive1(i,j)*(n-i+1)*(n-j+1);

    end
end
total
```

exclusive2:

```
function [y ] = exclusive2( ni,nj )

M=max(ni,nj);
m=min(ni,nj);
% corner not selected
sum0=0;
sum0=(M-1)*(M-1)*(m-1)*(m-1);
sum0

% one corner is chosen
sum1=0;
sum1=(M-1)*(m-1)*(M+m-2)*4; % one on side 1, one on side 2, one on side 3 or 4
if M>=3
    sum1=sum1+nchoosek(M-1,2)*(m-1)*4; % two on side 1, one on side 2
end
if m>=3
    sum1=sum1+nchoosek(m-1,2)*(M-1)*4; % two on side 2, one on side 1
end
sum1

% two corners are chosen
% corners are on same side
sum21=0;
sum21=(M-1)* 2*(m-1)*4;  % the 4 because 4 ways to select same side corners
                         % one on side 1 and one on side 2 or 3
if M>=3
    sum21=sum21+2*nchoosek(M-1,2); % two on side 1
end
if m>=3
    sum21=sum21+2*nchoosek(m-1,2); % two on side 2
end
sum21

% two corners are chosen
% different side
sum22=0;
sum22=(M-1)*(m-1)*2*2;  % picking two pts from one side of diagonal
                        % first *2 because diagonal splits it into two side
                        % second *2 because we can pick two pairs of different side corners
sum22=sum22+(M+m-2)*(M+m-2)*2;  
sum22

% three cor;ners
sum3=0;
sum3=4*(M-1+m-1);
sum3

% four corners
sum4=0;
sum4=1;

y=sum0+sum1+sum21+sum22+sum3+sum4;
end
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @CST-Link my calculation gives me 912, but i dont know where is wrong. sorry that i forgot to mention my calculation. i have edited it now

Comment: Does the standard sequence include quadrilaterals with 180-degree angles? I don't think you count those.

Comment: @DavidK i dont think i should count those, since in 2x2 case, 70 doesnt include 180-degree angles

Comment: OK, if you get 70 for a 2x2 then that was not the problem.

Comment: i figure it out. if grid is large, and three pts at corners, the 4th can be interior but not boundary